# How to do custom search functionality in job manager plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used job manager plugin in wordpress.
And my client want search functionality in admin section to search jobs.
whatever jobs added we save in wp_posts table.

below is the code

```
  $jobs = get_posts('post_type=jobman_job&numberposts=-1&post_status=publish,draft,future' );
```

in above code i want add `$post_title = $_POST['searchtext']`.

then how to add in existing code ?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters